# Hide my local network from ISP provided router/modem

Tags: networking, router, security, wireless-router, modem

I have a fiber connection in my house that's fiber directly connected to the ISP-provided modem, meaning the modem acts as a convertor from fiber to metallic and I can't get rid of it.
The modem also acts as a router and I can't switch it to bridge mode, as it offers no such setting.

I also have my own router (ASUS AX6000) connected to the modem (modem is connected to the WAN slot in the router), however, my router treats the modem as a part of the local network. I can access the modem when connected to the router and I can access the router when connected to the modem (admin interfaces). I can also ping other devices within the network when connected to the modem.

The modem is horribly outdated, insecure and the ISP has full remote control over modem. Is there any way I can make the router treat the ISP modem as WAN, meaning my local network will be hidden from the modem and the ISP?

I would be okay with buying other necessary equipment to make my network more secure.

Comment: What makes you think your internal network is accessible from by ISP? What you describe is actually normal. It would only be insecure if neither network was protected with a passphrase in the event the modem supported WiFi and you should be able to disable that.  Additionally, if it’s a huge concern, you should be able to replace the modem with hardware of your choice.

Comment: @Ramhound Like I said in the post, the ISP has full remote control over the modem. If I can access my home devices from the modem, so can the ISP right? Also the modem receives no security updates, so if anyone was able to compromise the modem (other users within the same ISP network), they would be able to access my home network too. I want to to achieve that the modem would be treated strictly as WAN, as if it was in the bridge mode (if that's posible). I am a newbie into networking and want to know whether that's something that is possible to do.

Comment: Having full control over the modem doesn't mean they can see into your network. That would bring some pretty serious legal ramifications if they did. What you describe is how most modem/routers work - especially in jurisdictions where you cannot just swap to your own personal router [the UK is like this, routers are code-locked to the ISP; swap for your own & it won't connect.]

Comment: @Daniel - “If I can access my home devices from the modem, so can the ISP right?” - No; Your not listening when I and others say it’s normal for a device connected to modem like you describe, to be able to access a network created by a router, the fact this can be done does not mean  devices on the intranet can be remotely accessed

Comment: @Ramhound I am 100% aware this does not mean my network devices can be accessed remotely. I am cornerned about exploitation of the ISP modem. The changes of this are RARE, yes, I am aware. However, the modem does not receive any security updates, it is running an ancient version of Linux and ISP can remotely push software to the modem. In case the ISP is compromised or supply chain for the modem is compromised, this would mean the compromise of my entire network. If it would be possible to switch the modem to the bridge mode, it would eliminate the risk, but it's not.

Comment: @Daniel - You are aware you can purchase your own modem and tell your ISP that you will be using that and have them provision it to their network? You could in theory get yourself a L3 switch, create a VLAN, so only devices on the VLAN you want can access the internet. Doing so doesn’t necessarily make your network more secure.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried reasoning with the ISP but this ISP won't provide any support to running own devices. They won't even provide a guide to setup network authentication on a 3rd party devices. With my previous ISP, I was running my own fiber to metallic convertor and then my own router doing authentication to the network. This ISP won't provide any support and it's the only ISP available in my new house.

Comment: Even if you were to have the ISP modem into bridge mode (which they should be able to do), they can also switch it back to normal. But as others said, your router protects you from the internet, and because you are on the inside of the network, you can access both the admin router and your internal network. If you don't open ports on your own router, all you can access from the internet is your router, assuming you at least open a port to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not trust the ISP Modem/Router and you cannot exchange it by your own device you have to use a firewall as the sole connection to the not-trusted device.

There are firewall solutions out there that run on a Raspberry PI or similar lightweight PCs.
In the simplest case you have an old "Internet Router" that can assign a network jack as a WAN port:

```
      Internet
         |
        ISP
- - - - -|- - - - - 
ISP's Modem/Router
         |
     Firewall —— DMZ — Your_Web-/Pers.Cloud-/Game-Server
         |
      (W)LAN
        /|\
 hosts 1 2 3 ...
```

A firewall solution offers more sophisticated configuration options than a fully integrated "Internet-Router" and can also provide a DMZ, a second network without access to your secure LAN. There you could securely host servers that shall be accessible from the internet, without exposing your secure LAN.